# How to get total years, months and days in odoo

Tags: python

My example:

Print returns

> Years=1 Months=5 Days=15

```
import datetime
import math
new_date = datetime.datetime(2017,1,1)
differnce = datetime.datetime.now() - new_date
year = differnce.days//(365.25)
month = (differnce.days-year*365.25)//(365.25/12)
day = ((differnce.days-year*365.25) - month*(365.25/12))
print('Years=',int(year),' Months=',int(month), ' Days=',int(math.ceil(day)))

year_2 = 1
month_2 = 1
days_2 = 1
```

How to get difference as 2 years, 6 months and 16 days?

Comment: Why do you want to get 2 years, 6 months? As I supposed you don't have tweaked your computer's clock, today (2018-06-18) there has transcurred 1 year, 5 months and 17 days since 2017-01-01 (your base date). I suppose you ask for 16 days since you tested it yesterday (June-17th)...

Comment: What does [tag:oodo] have to do with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use [dateutil](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

new_date = datetime.datetime(2017,1,1)
difference = relativedelta(datetime.datetime.now(), new_date)
difference
# relativedelta(years=+1, months=+5, days=+17, hours=+10, minutes=+22, seconds=+36, microseconds=+281175)

new_difference = difference + relativedelta(years=1, months=1, days=1)
new_difference
# relativedelta(years=+2, months=+6, days=+18, hours=+10, minutes=+22, seconds=+36, microseconds=+281175)
```

Comment: Tnx for help, Do you know any simple example how convert eg. 370 days in format (1 year, 0 montth, 5 days) Tnx!